# How can I reproduce this semi-random pixel background?

Tags: language-agnostic, graphics, buffer, initialization

I've seen this kind of noisy background in some pre-release versions of browsers and operating systems:

[image: pixel noise]

It is not exactly *random*, i.e. it's not just white noise.
How do I achieve the same effect on purpose?

I thought this might have to do with fogetting to clear graphic buffer before drawing but I have no idea.
If it is just a memory garbage, how come the colors are mostly the same?

Is this something common across different graphic libraries?
Can I reproduce this (in any language, with any graphic library, on OS X, Windows or Linux)?

(This is a screenshot of Safari on OS X but I'm sure I saw this on Windows once as well.)

Comment: It almost looks like the result of an incorrect (or inconsistent) stride in a bitmap... Just a thought.

Comment: You truly want to reproduce this? Or simply want to know what causes this? If the former is the case, I would not go the programming route, but perhaps try to reproduce it in a graphics package (Photoshop, Gimp, ...)

Comment: I want to understand why it happens, and to prove that my understanding is correct, to be able to reproduce it as well. I'll look into what a stride is, thank you @Corey for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen many of similar images in my own programs, usually it happens when the correct image of one width is drawn on the image of the different width. So the pixels get displaced.

consider this quick example:

```
4x4 image:
****
*  *
*  *
****

roll into one memory region:
*****  **  *****

same image with width 3:
***
** 
 **
  *
***
*

same width width 5:
*****
  ** 
 ****
*
```

so with larger images and width2 = width1 +/- (width1 * 0.1) you could get similar results.
often images are also not black/white and the original pixel format may different from the output pixel format adding more effects like strange colors.